# Search between character and first white space

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the number from this string REG/123 which is between REG/ and a white space.

I tried the following codes, though they only take the last white space in the line.

```
test=line[line.find("REG/")+len("REG/"):line.rfind(" ")]

test=re.search('REG/(.*)" "',line)
```

Comment: `re.search('REG\/(\d*)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line = 'I am trying to extract the number from this string REG/123 which is between REG/ and a white space.'
number = re.search(r'(?<=\bREG/)\d+', line).group(0)
print(number)
```

**Output:**

```
123
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=        # positive lookbehind, make sure we have before:
  \b        # a word boundary
  REG/      # literally REG/ string
)           # end lookbehind
\d+         # 1 or more digits
```

Answer (score 1):

What i end up doing is the following code and its working for me, i replaced the spaces with a specific character then did regex.

```
       line = line.replace(" ", "#")


       test=re.search(r'REG/(.*?)#', line).group(1)  

       print(test)
```

Comment: This will match `GREG/abc123`, is that what you want? Why don't you use [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650356/372239)

Answer (score 0):

For pattern like 'REG/123', regex will be `r'^REG/\d+$'`

`test=re.search(r'^REG/\d+$',line)`

After getting all the matches, you can run a loop to extract only the number by splitting the string with `.split("/")[1]`

Answer (score 0):

you could extract the integer value from the string by using regular expression matching characters.

```
text = "REG/123"
re.search(r'\d+', text)

o/p: 123

or 
re.findall(r'\d+', text)

o/p: 123
```

**Explanation:**

"\d" - Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to the class [0-9].

"+" - one or more integers